# how to decouple complex Qt widget classes

Tags: c++, qt, widget

I have lots of custom Qt widgets that have their own layouts and contain lists of even more widgets.
I ended up having a ManagerWidget that controls everything (including listening to all events) and propagating them to the widget that needs to update its content. It seems there are too many methods that just pass the information along.

Is there a better way of doing this? Connecting the classes through signal/slots doesn't really work in this case because there's a map of them and I wouldn't know which one was fired.
Would the Mediator pattern fit in this case?

```
class ManagerWidget : public QWidget {

public:
  map<ID, MainWidgetContainer*> mainWidgetMap;
  RecordsContainer *recentRecords; // This widget can contain any number of widgets, each showing a record

 // events are caught here and propagated to the widgets
  void AddNewEntry(ID id) {
    MainWidgetContainer *w = new MainWidgetContainer(id);
    mainWidgetMap.insert(id, w);
  }

  void UpdatePictureWidget(ID id) { 
     mainWidgetMap.value(id)->UpdatePictureWidget();
  }
  void AddXItem(ID id, Type1 k) { 
    if(id == 0)
        recentRecords->AddXItem(k);
    else
        mainWidgetMap.value(id)->AddXItem(k);
  }

  void UpdateEntry(ID id, string newName) {  }

};

class MainWidgetContainer : public QWidget {
public:
  NameWidget *name;
  PictureWidget *pic;
  RecordsContainer *records; // This widget can contain any number of widgets, each showing a record

  MainWidgetContainer(ID id) { 
   name = new NameWidget(id); 
   records = new RecordsContainer();
   pic = new PictureWidget();
   // setup layout and add items to records as they come in later
  }

  AddXItem(Type1 k) { records->AddXItem(k); } 
  UpdatePictureWidget() { pic->Update(); }

};

class RecordsContainer : public QWidget {
public:
  map<Type1, Item*> itemMap;

  AddXItem(Type1 k) { 
   Item *item = new Item(k);
   itemMap.insert(k, item);
   mainLayout->addWidget(item);
  }
  AddYItem(Type2 k);
  // etc

};
```

Comment: Why connect signals to parent widgets and then re-signal them? Just connect to the widget you want it to catch the signal.

Comment: So in `ManagerWidget::AddXItem(ID id, Type1 k)` I would do: 
`mainWidgetMap.value(id)->AddXItem(k);
connect(this, SIGNAL(UpdateItemName(QString&), mainWidgetMap.value(id)->records.value(k), SLOT(UpdateName(QString&)));`
Isn't that coupled too tightly?